# Java/Weka - Need to create unique instances

Tags: java, weka

I wonder if there is a method that checks whether my new instance has been already created and added to my instances in Java...
Like ;

```
Instance instance = new Instance(i, vals);
if(instances.contains(instance) == false) { //or hasInstance maybe
    instances.add(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand, that you want for two objects `x1` and `x2` with `x1.equals(x2)` that x1 is the same instance (`x1 == x2`).

One needs to do something like this:

```
private Map<Instance, Instance> identityMap = new HashMap<>();

public Instance unique(Instance instance) {
    Instance first = identityMap.get(instance);
    if (first == null) {
        first = instance;
        identityMap.put(instance, instance);
    }
    return first;
}

Instance instance = new Instance(i, vals);
instance = unique(instance);
```

The reason is, that you want to maintain the *first* instance, to be used by all.

---

By the way - *for other purposes*:

```
Set<Instance> instances = ...;
```

Instead of

```
if (!instances.contains(instance)) { // if not instances contains
```

one could use code like

```
if (instances.add(instance)) {
    // Added, hence new...
} else {
    // Not added, hence already existing...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Your answer encourages me ^^ and now i got 1000 unique instances yup.
Your answer brings me to the solution but i use my own method;

private static boolean hasInstance(Instance instance) {
   Instance first = identityMap.get(instance);
   if(first == null) {
    return false;
   }
   else {
    return true;
   }
  }

Comment: `return first != null;` is nicer style ;).